# Opening a link in a new tab in a PHP echo statement

Tags: php, html

Relatively new to PHP and I am uingd PHP to produce a table that is populated with records from a Database, and have a column in the 'echo' table which is a hyperlink. Is there a simple way in which i could get the link to open a new browser tab once clicked? Relevant code is below...

```
echo "<tr align = center bgcolor=white><td><b><a href=view_rfp_detail.php?sna=$sna >$sna</a></b></td><td>$ques</a></td><td>$ans</a></td>";
```

Thanks

Comment: Also so as not to confuse OP the problem you were having was a HTML issue not PHP

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to open a new tab try target = blank in anchor tab

```
<a target = '_blank' href=view_rfp_detail.php?sna=$sna >$sna</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `target="_blank"` into your a tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
echo "<tr align = center bgcolor=white><td><b><a target=\"_blank\" href=view_rfp_detail.php?sna=$sna >$sna</a></b></td><td>$ques</a></td><td>$ans</a></td>";
```

However based on how the user has their browser configured, this may open the link in a new tab or a new window.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo <<<TR
<tr style="text-align: center; background: white">
  <td>
    <strong><a href="view_rfp_detail.php?sna={$sna}" target="_blank">{$sna}</a></strong>
  </td>
  <td>{$ques}</td>
  <td>{$ans}</td>
</tr>
TR
```

FTFY

Answer (score 0):

You could also use javascript which provides the same functionality and gets round strict validation errors.

```
<a onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" href=view_rfp_detail.php?sna=$sna >$sna</a>
```